# Overly strict question limiting?

Tags: support, post-ban

I wasn't familiar with question blocking on SE though it makes sense. But I've just been temp-blocked:

> You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been
>   received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own
>   pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your
>   questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account
>   from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been 1 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you
>   wait 1 days before asking again.

I wasn't aware I'd asked negatively received questions, or asked many questions recently, so I had a look - here are my questions on this SE site.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/24891/mr-boy?tab=questions&sort=newest

[image]

So I've asked a question yesterday which received a single downvote. *all* my other questions have a positive score and until yesterday, 3 of my 4 questions have answers, and I've accepted answers on them too.

Before yesterday my last question was in December.

So my questions are:

1. How is two questions in the last *8 months* "You've asked 2 questions recently" ?
2. How is a single downvote on a single question, which was only asked yesterday, "some of which have not been received very well by the community." ?

From my limited view of the data it appears a single downvote has triggered a temp-block. I'm an SE user of almost 9 years, on 33 communities, with hundreds of questions, answers, badges, etc... surely that's not how the system should work?

Comment: Do you have any deleted questions? Those count, you know. However, I don't know why your latest question was downvoted; it seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @ale not that I'm aware of assuming I would be able to see them (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/24891) as a new user to this specific SE site obviously I can't see all the votes and moderator actions I can on sites like SO where I've 20k rep

Comment: A Moderator would be needed to check your history of all deleted questions. Perhaps one of them can provide further insight. I wonder if SE tightened the controls, even if temporarily? (I haven't seen anything on [meta.se].)